# Regex to extract time from a time string

Tags: regex

I have time string in the format of "PT8H6M3.831S" or "PT1M34.57S" or "PT0S" based on time availability. I want to extract hour, minutes, and seconds parts from these strings if possible using regex.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, you have to try and show us what has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Start building your regex from the constant parts "PT" at the beginning. Then use optional groups to capture the two elements of Hour and Minute. Second seems always to be here, so it is not optional group which ends the regex. Then use the number of groups matched to determine how many groups where there.

Hints:

- Regex at beginning `^`
- Constant values in regex just as they are `PT`
- Optional group `( )?`
- Required group `( )`
- End of regex `$`

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can you please provide me a regex expression? I tried but it's not working correctly

Comment: Please update your question with what you already have and what errors you get

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it working with `^PT(?:(?<H>\d*\.?\d*)H)?(?:(?<M>\d*\.?\d*)M)?(?:(?<S>\d*\.?\d*)S)?$`